# How to search in XML file using php?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I don't know if there is a method to search in xml file. For instance. I want to get the **Value** using the **Name** from **AttrList** and the **ProductCode**. Is it possible ? This is how my xml look likes:

```
<Product>
    <ProductCode>70-14UF44-00</ProductCode>
    <Vendor>NBM</Vendor>
    <ProductType>Soft. Unsorted application</ProductType>
    <ProductCategory>Software</ProductCategory>
    <ProductDescription>{Bluetooth Driver IVT V.1.4.9.3, 1pk, Full Package, OEM, 1pk for 12M3W/15G3WS, 1pk, 1pk}</ProductDescription>
    <Image>https://www.it4profit.com/catalogimg/wic/1/70-14UF44-00</Image>
    <ProductCard>https://content.it4profit.com/itshop/itemcard_cs.jsp?ITEM=50409104050320315&amp;THEME=asbis&amp;LANG=ro</ProductCard>
    <AttrList>
      <element Name="Tipul licentei" Value="Full Package"/>
      <element Name="License Conditions" Value="OEM"/>
      <element Name="Produs de baza(1)" Value="12M3W/15G3WS"/>
      <element Name="Greutatea bruta a pachetului" Value="1.546 kg"/>
      <element Name="Bucati in pachet" Value="1"/>
    </AttrList>
    <MarketingInfo>
      <element></element>
    </MarketingInfo>
    <Images/>
  </Product>
```

Im using the **SimpleXML** libraries from **PHP**
Trying with DOMDocument:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->Load('produse_catalog.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$query = '//ProductCatalog/Product/ProductCode[. = "PMP5297C_QUAD"]';

$entries = $xpath->query($query);
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    echo "Found {$entry->previousSibling->previousSibling->nodeValue}," .
    " by {$entry->previousSibling->nodeValue}\n";
}
```

The result is: **Notice: Trying to get property of non-object**. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Take a look at `SimpleXMLElement::xpath` http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

Comment: I looked over it, but i don't undestand how could it be possible to integrate this in my case. Could you post o sample? i would really appreaciate it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can use simplexml with xpath in this case:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('path/to/xml/file.xml');
$name = 'Tipul licentei';
$product_code = '70-14UF44-00';
$products = $xml->xpath("//Product/ProductCode[contains(text(), '$product_code')]/following-sibling::AttrList/element[@Name='$name']");
if(count($products) > 0) { // if found

    $value = (string) $products[0]->attributes()->Value;
    echo $value; // Full Package

}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/FIHtFF)

Also possible with DOMDocument:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('path/to/xml/file.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$name = 'Tipul licentei';
$product_code = '70-14UF44-00';
$value = $xpath->evaluate("string(//Product/ProductCode[contains(text(), '$product_code')]/following-sibling::AttrList/element[@Name='$name']/@Value)");
echo $value; // Full Package
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting simplexml_load_file over using DOMDocument.

Comment: @killneel actually domdocument is also okay in this case. its possible with both. you can choose which one you're comfortable with

Answer (score 2):

You can use the DOMXPath for this purpose. 
Example taken from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php)

```
  $doc = new DOMDocument;
  $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
  $doc->Load('book.xml');
  $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
  // We starts from the root element
 $query = '//book/chapter/para/informaltable/tgroup/tbody/row/entry[. = "en"]';

 $entries = $xpath->query($query);

 foreach ($entries as $entry) {
   echo "Found {$entry->previousSibling->previousSibling->nodeValue}," .
     " by {$entry->previousSibling->nodeValue}\n";
  }
```