# Search XML file with PHP?

Tags: php

I have this XML file `getItems.php`:

```
<items>
  <item name="Designer: X091" price="300">
    <det set="10">
      <data>
        <![CDATA[
        [{"c": 10092, "l": "", "hasItem": false}]
        ]]>
      </data>
    </det>
  </item>
  <item name="Designer: X091" price="10">
    <det set="2">
      <data>
        <![CDATA[
        [{"c": 19920, "l": "", "hasItem": false}]
        ]]>
      </data>
    </det>
  </item>
</items>
```

What I would like to do is extract the items' name and price, and the `det`'s set number, and what's inside `data` to variables, and I would like to use `foreach` so I can get each item, **if the item's name is "Designer: X091"**.

I was trying  this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26547493/6568271) but I got kinda confused with `xpath` and would like some help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have a working example of the use of **SimpleXML** to search that particular element and show its information.

I have used a `while` loop instead a `foreach` to stop the search when you find the element you want.

```
<?php

$string = '
<items>
  <item name="Designer: X091" price="300">
    <det set="10">
      <data>
        <![CDATA[
        [{"c": 10092, "l": "", "hasItem": false}]
        ]]>
      </data>
    </det>
  </item>
  <item name="Designer: X091" price="10">
    <det set="2">
      <data>
        <![CDATA[
        [{"c": 19920, "l": "", "hasItem": false}]
        ]]>
      </data>
    </det>
  </item>
</items>';

$obj = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

$searchedName = 'Designer: X091';
$numberOfItems = count($obj->item);
$i = 0;

// While you don't find it and there're elements left, look for the next

while($obj->item[$i]['name'] != $searchedName && $i < $numberOfItems){
  $i++;
}

// If the counter is NOT less than number of items, we didn't find it

if($i == $numberOfItems){
  echo 'Item not found';
}

// Else, we know the position of the item in the object

else{
  $price = $obj->item[$i]['price'];
  $detSet = $obj->item[$i]->det['set'];
  $data = $obj->item[$i]->det->data;
}

echo "Name: $searchedName<br>";
echo "Price: $price<br>";
echo "Det set: $detSet<br>";
echo "Data: $data<br>";
```

The output is:

```
Name: Designer: X091
Price: 300
Det set: 10
Data: [{"c": 10092, "l": "", "hasItem": false}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your XML to `$xmlString` variable, then:

```
// create a new instance of SimpleXMLElement
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);
$results = [];

// check how many elements are in your xml
if ($xml->count() > 0) {

    // if more than 0, then create loop
    foreach ($xml->children() as $xmlChild) {

        // assign attributes to $attr variable
        $attr = $xmlChild->attributes();

        // check if your attrs are defined
        if (isset($attr['name']) && isset($attr['price'])) {

            // attach values to $results array
            $results[] = [
                'name' => (string)$attr['name'],
                'price' => (int)$attr['price']
            ];
        }
    }
}
```

Then variable `$results` should looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Designer: X091
            [price] => 300
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Designer: X091
            [price] => 10
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks for this! :)